# SQL Intelligent Joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, relational-database

```
;WITH tblEmployee AS (
SELECT * FROM (VALUES
(1, 'Tom', 'Male', 4000, 1),
(2, 'Pam', 'Female', 3000, 3),
(3, 'John', 'Male', 3500, 1),
(4, 'Sam', 'Male', 4500, 2),
(5, 'Todd', 'Male', 2800, 2),
(6, 'Ben', 'Male', 7000, 1),
(7, 'Sara', 'Female', 4800, 3),
(8, 'Valarie', 'Female', 5500, 1),
(9, 'James', 'Male', 6500, NULL),
(10, 'Russell', 'Male', 8800, NULL)) AS E(ID, Name, Gender, Salary, DepartmentId)
), 
tblDepartment AS (
SELECT * FROM (VALUES
(1, 'IT', 'London', 'Rick'),
(2, 'Payroll', 'Delhi', 'Ron'),
(3, 'HR', 'New York', 'Christie'),
(4, 'Other Department', 'Sydney', 'Cindrella')) AS D(Id, DepartmentName, Location, DepartmentHead)
)
```

Left table is employee table and right tables department table.

I am following a tutorial online and am confused by the explanation the instructor provided:

If I run this query on the two tables above:

```
Select E.Name, E.Gender, E.Salary, D.DepartmentName
from tblEmployee as E
Left Join tblDepartment as D
On tblEmployee.departmentID = tblDepartment.Id
Where tblEmployee.departmentID IS Null;
```

I am a little confused on what the last line in the SQL code above does. When you say:

```
Where tblEmployee.departmentID IS Null
```

Is the above line of code being executed on the new table that is formed after these lines of code are run:

```
Select E.Name, E.Gender, E.Salary, D.DepartmentName
from tblEmployee as E
Left Join tblDepartment as D
On tblEmployee.departmentID = tblDepartment.Id
```

So basically it checks on the new table formed: only where you have the department ID as NULL show me those rows. I just wanted to clarify that this line: `Where tblEmployee.departmentID IS Null` is being run after the new table is formed correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. First the tables are joined, and then the WHERE clause effects the results.

Comment: Ok, thank you! Also for some reason when I do `Where tbDepartment.ID IS Null` in the last line of the SQL code it gives me same result? Do you know why that is the case? So basically these lines: `Where tbDepartment.ID IS Null` or `Where tblEmployee.departmentID IS Null` gives me the same result.

Comment: Actually , the correct query is Where tbDepartment.ID is null , because it is the right table.. the left table keep all results so if it doesn't have null values on ID it cant be null. I doubt that it returns the same results because it doesn't looks like emp.id can be null

Comment: How do you know I have to put that where clause against the right table and not the left table?

Comment: Because you are using a LEFT JOIN, meaning all the records from the left table will be kept, and only the matches from the right table will be kept.

Comment: Ohh, that makes sense. So you only check on the right table since you will have one or more rows from the right table that does not match specific rows from the left table so you need to check against that to get all the rows that are only present in the left table.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105475/discussion-between-kb3-and-sagi).

Answer (score 1):

This is a Left Outer Join. This will take all records from `tblEmployee` that do not join to `tblDepartment`.

[image]

Comment: Yes I am aware that this is a left join but my question was not specifically about left outer joins!

Answer (score 1):

"SQL Intelligent Joins" is a rare phrasing. In fact, the only solid reference (as well as the dataset in this question) comes from a YouTube SQL tutorial:

[Advanced or Intelligent Joins by Kudvenkat](https://youtu.be/GKGtOABAO9s?t=199)

In short, "intelligent joins" are cleaner in syntax, and far more explicit in declaring the boundaries of your dataset. Take the following two queries for example. They have equivalent output, but different syntax:

```
-- intelligent join
select
    e.Name,
    e.Gender,
    e.Salary

from tblEmployee as e
    left join tblDepartment as d on e.departmentID = d.Id
        and d.DepartmentName = 'IT'

where
    d.DepartmentName is null
```

This query above uses an "intelligent join".

```
-- where clause subquery
select
    e.Name,
    e.Gender,
    e.Salary

from tblEmployee as e

where
    e.departmentID not in (select id from tblDepartment where departmentName = 'IT')
    or e.departmentID is null
```

This query above uses a subquery in the `where` clause.

But even though the two outputs are equivalent, the first query is simpler and gives more information. It essentially says "Give me all employees' gender and salary if they are NOT in the IT department". In contrast, the `where` clause subquery syntax is longer and muddles how the tables join. If anything, try to achieve your desired output using intelligent joins first.

Comment: The idea is to use additional criteria within the join statement to further define the specific filtering that only affects that join. This is not a good example of an 'Intelligent' join because the difference is not clear enough. In fact it's a bit nonsenical, to join on IT departments and then finally filter out all departments?  In your example there is a third variant, using traditional join syntax but only specifying the primary linking field and moving  `and d.departmentName = 'IT'`  to the outer `WHERE`, in this example you are saying WHERE DepartmentName IS NULL AND IT...

Answer (score 0):

OP's assumption is correct, the following are a few aspects about `SQL` *JOIN* syntax that will be helpful for beginners to understand once they have grasped the concept of what a *join* is. Its often not enough to know that something is correct or works, we need to understand the reasons behind it.

> [This answer from @fqhv](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35831334/1690217) uses one of my personal favorite info-graphics about the different type of joins.

Firstly, be aware of the execution order of a query, [this reference is a good general explanation](https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/sql-query-order-of-operations), Note that each database engine can and might do things differently, but this is a generally solid expectation.

[image: Execution Order of SQL Statements]

an important takeaway is this:

> Join statements are actually part of the `FROM` clause in your query

Notice how the `select` statement is evaluated *after* the filtering has occurred, this means that up until that point we can consider the `FROM` clause to present a very wide table that includes *ALL* columns from *ALL* of the tables expressed in the `FROM` clause.

You can demonstrate this by using the field wildcard (`*`, asterix) in the select statement instead of specifying any specific fields. 
- In this example I will comment out the `SELECT` and the `WHERE` clause to demonstrate a common technique for debugging or investigating SQL results.
- NOTE: as table aliases are used in the `FROM` clause, I have changed the query to use those aliases instead of the table name, this query will actually run now.
- We expect that all columns, and all rows will be returned in the following query

```
-- Select E.Name, E.Gender, E.Salary, D.DepartmentName
SELECT *
from tblEmployee as E
Left Join tblDepartment as D
On E.departmentID = D.Id
-- Where E.departmentID IS Null;
```

```
ID          Name    Gender Salary      DepartmentId Id          DepartmentName   Location DepartmentHead
----------- ------- ------ ----------- ------------ ----------- ---------------- -------- --------------
1           Tom     Male   4000        1            1           IT               London   Rick
2           Pam     Female 3000        3            3           HR               New York Christie
3           John    Male   3500        1            1           IT               London   Rick
4           Sam     Male   4500        2            2           Payroll          Delhi    Ron
5           Todd    Male   2800        2            2           Payroll          Delhi    Ron
6           Ben     Male   7000        1            1           IT               London   Rick
7           Sara    Female 4800        3            3           HR               New York Christie
8           Valarie Female 5500        1            1           IT               London   Rick
9           James   Male   6500        NULL         NULL        NULL             NULL     NULL
10          Russell Male   8800        NULL         NULL        NULL             NULL     NULL

(10 rows affected)
```

Hopefully, looking at the results from the query really should paint the picture in your mind of the fields that are available to select from and to filter on.

You will notice that using the `LEFT JOIN` has caused some rows to contain only `NULL` values for the fields from the `tblDepartment` table. This can be very powerful, a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

- `OUTER` is the default modifier for a JOIN if `OUTER` or `INNER` is not specified. It is equally valid to referred to this as a `LEFT JOIN`

will return at least 1 the row for every result from the *LEFT* of the current `JOIN` statement, AKA all the fields previously JOINed onto the `FROM` clause, even if there are no matching rows in the table we have just JOINed.

With this information, when we want a listing of all students that are not in any department, we can simply use the `LEFT JOIN` behaviour of inserting nulls to easily identify the rows to remove.

When `Where E.departmentID IS Null` is added to the query, only the rows that do not have a department will be returned.

```
-- Select E.Name, E.Gender, E.Salary, D.DepartmentName
SELECT *
from tblEmployee as E
Left Join tblDepartment as D
On E.departmentID = D.Id
Where E.departmentID IS Null;
```

```
ID          Name    Gender Salary      DepartmentId Id          DepartmentName   Location DepartmentHead
----------- ------- ------ ----------- ------------ ----------- ---------------- -------- --------------
9           James   Male   6500        NULL         NULL        NULL             NULL     NULL
10          Russell Male   8800        NULL         NULL        NULL             NULL     NULL
```

> Its worth stating the obvious, this is a really simple example, and similar results could have been achieved without using a `JOIN` at all but it is a good dataset to demonstrate all types of JOINs.

For instance, a `RIGHT JOIN` will return atleast ONE row for each result in the JOINed table, even if there are no matching rows from the previously JOINed fields.

```
SELECT *
from tblEmployee as E
RIGHT Join tblDepartment as D
On E.departmentID = D.Id
```

```
ID          Name    Gender Salary      DepartmentId Id          DepartmentName   Location DepartmentHead
----------- ------- ------ ----------- ------------ ----------- ---------------- -------- --------------
1           Tom     Male   4000        1            1           IT               London   Rick
3           John    Male   3500        1            1           IT               London   Rick
6           Ben     Male   7000        1            1           IT               London   Rick
8           Valarie Female 5500        1            1           IT               London   Rick
4           Sam     Male   4500        2            2           Payroll          Delhi    Ron
5           Todd    Male   2800        2            2           Payroll          Delhi    Ron
2           Pam     Female 3000        3            3           HR               New York Christie
7           Sara    Female 4800        3            3           HR               New York Christie
NULL        NULL    NULL   NULL        NULL         4           Other Department Sydney   Cindrella
```

Using this information we can now easily filter the results to show all departments that have *ZERO* employees:

```
SELECT *
from tblEmployee as E
RIGHT Join tblDepartment as D
On E.departmentID = D.Id
Where E.ID IS Null;
```

```
ID          Name    Gender Salary      DepartmentId Id          DepartmentName   Location DepartmentHead
----------- ------- ------ ----------- ------------ ----------- ---------------- -------- --------------
NULL        NULL    NULL   NULL        NULL         4           Other Department Sydney   Cindrella
```

---

## SQL Intelligent Joins

This is a bit of click bait really, it's not a term you will find many books all agreeing on, but the idea behind it we all subscribe to:

> a good SQL programmer or DBA should develop a skill in how to translate a query requirement and *intelligently* apply `JOIN` statements to simplify the requirement.

Many problems where your developer instinct is to iterate through a collection can be solved using an *inteligent* application of JOINs, not all, but many. So when you first think *iterate* take some time to explore different `JOIN` statements on your data query.

You can of course make queries implementing `JOIN` statements and complex `WHERE` clauses *more* intelligent and easier to read by moving filter criteria that operates specifically on the JOINed table into the `JOIN` expression itself, its out of the scope of OPs original question to go through this with this dataset but [@alexusWong goes into this in his response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59462457/1690217)

- don't fall into the trap of assuming your can only JOIN *ON* a single field comparison, you can use almost all standard `WHERE` statements as additional criteria for your `JOIN` statemet.